# How to rename a file to the parent's parent folder name in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

so I have a bunch of folders with similar directories to the below:

```
.\page\1\randomStringofCharacters\randomStringofCharactersAgain.png
.\page\2\randomStringofCharacters\randomStringofCharactersAgain.png
.\page\3\randomStringofCharacters\randomStringofCharactersAgain.png
```

I want to rename all the `.png` files the number just before the first `randomStringofCharacters`. So basically

```
.\page\1\randomStringofCharacters\randomStringofCharactersAgain.png -> 1.png
.\page\2\randomStringofCharacters\randomStringofCharactersAgain.png -> 2.png
.\page\3\randomStringofCharacters\randomStringofCharactersAgain.png -> 3.png
```

Is there any batch script that can do this? I have tried:

```sh
@Echo OFF

FOR /D /R %%# in (*) DO (
    PUSHD "%%#"
    FOR %%@ in ("*.png") DO (
        Echo Ren: ".\%%~n#\%%@" "%%~n#%%~x@"
        Ren "%%@" "%%~n#%%~x@"
    )
    POPD
)

Pause&Exit
```

Yet this only renames the file with the parent directory.

And if possible is there a way to move all such renamed .png files in to a newly made folder in `.\page\` (the same place where the .bat is) with the folder name of page?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Kind of going about it the wrong way.  Get the png files first.  Then determine the parent folder name from that.  Simple code to get the parent directory. This will be your inner FOR command to get the parent. `for %%G in ("%%~dp#\.") do set parent=%%~nxG`

Comment: And if you want two folders up. `for %%G in ("%%~dp#\..") do set GrandParent=%%~nxG`

Comment: If the items are at a certain directory hierarchy depth, you should not use `for /R`, because it returns the whole directory tree…

Comment: As far as I'm concerned this idea currently is not robust enough. To begin with, the standard glob `*.png`, as you are using, does not usually only identify files with a `.png` extension, _(it matches on 8.3 names, so possibly matches, for instance, `.pngx` extensions too)_. It should also be 100% certain that there is no more than one matching file in each directory, to prevent failed rename conflicts, _(you cannot have multiple files named `1.png`, `2.png`, and `3.png` in the same location)_. Also a standard `for` loop does not enumerate all files, _(hidden ones, for instance are ignored)_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be something like this (you have to drag and drop the main folder to the batch):

```
@echo off

if exist "%~1" (IF not exist "%~1\" exit) else (exit)
if /i not exist "%~dp0Page" md "%~dp0Page"

pushd "%~1"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b *.png') do Call :Rename "%%~a" "%%~dpa"
exit

:Rename
set Cpath=%~2
set Cpath=%Cpath:~0,-1%
For %%a in ("%Cpath%") do set Cpath=%%~dpa
set Cpath=%Cpath:~0,-1%
for %%a in ("%Cpath%") do set NName=%%~nxa
move "%~1" "%~dp0Page\%NName%%~x1"
goto :EOF
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `for /R` to handle items in a predefined directory hierarchy depth:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Iterate through the numeric target sub-directories (`1`, `2`, `3`, etc.):
for /D %%K in (".\page\*") do (
    rem // Iterate through sub-sub-directories `randomStringofCharacters`:
    for /D %%J in ("%%~K\*") do (
        rem // Iterate through `.png` files:
        for %%I in ("%%~J\*.png") do (
            rem // Actually rename the current file:
            ren "%%~I" "%%~nxK%%~xI"
        )
    )
)
```

Note, that this approach does not check whether there is only one `.png` file at each location.